# How to create Miniview Panel for Fabric Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, panel

How to create a mini view panel on my Fabric Canvas[MiniView Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa9Gg.png). As shown in the image i want a panel in the corner of my canvas where we can see the whole layout.

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/ just like this panel in the mentioned web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the contents of your main canvas and inject it into an `Image` with a specific size that is smaller than your main canvas.

See this answer: [Fabric.js canvas toDataUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566723/fabric-js-canvas-todataurl)